# Fetch table data from database without a model related to it

Tags: django, sqlite

Im looking for a way to fetch some data to display to the user.(Run a raw sql query like)

```
select * from "DB-table" where Name like "%blabla%" and Year like "%2020%"
```

My problem is that the "DB-table" lives in my database but its already populated with important data which is not related to some model in my django-app. Its a standalone table with a lot of data.
How can i refer to that table from my views.py file?

Comment: You can make a model that is not managed, this would allow you to use the ORM. An unmanaged model would be ignored by migrations. You can even use [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) to generate the model from the table

Comment: Alright friend okay. I will consider the above, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly my question was not so hard..But as im new to django and python i overcomplicated things. I managed to fetch the data i wanted using something like

```
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM  'Nvd-data'")
        res = cursor.fetchall()
        print(res)
```

For more advanced queries i think django documentation is fine.Hope that silly question helps someone